# building ffmpeg for windows x264.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I am building `ffmpeg` using `MSYS2` in `windows` system.

My compilation package is "`i686-8.1.0-release-posix-dwarf`" of `mingw`.

My configure option parameters are as follows:

`./configure --prefix="D:\fkit\b" --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-ffserver --enable-ffplay --disable-debug --disable-iconv --disable-zlib --extra-ldflags="-LD:\fkit\xb\lib -lx264" --extra-cflags="-ID:\ fkit\xb\include" --pkgconfigdir="D:\fkit\xb\lib\pkgconfig"`

As you can see, "D:fkit\xb" is my libx264 installation directory. I configured --extra-cflags and --extra-ldflags, and the configure script executed fine. But when I execute mingw32-make.exe, it prompts "`libavcodec/libx264.c:36:10: fatal error: x264.h: No such file or directory`"

I don't have any ideas because everything I do seems normal.

Comment: maybe "--extra-ldflags" and "--extra-cflags" is wrong?